# Repeatedly Choose Number From List and Lockout Chosen Numbers

Tags: python

I am writing a program for a game I am creating, and I need to get the following:

1. A number chosen from a range, probably 1-100.
2. That number printed, will be turned into a display for the user later.
3. Have that number locked out of being chosen again.

Due to the line of events, I cannot simply get all of the numbers pre-selected, they need to be selected in real time.

```
from random import *
number = randint(1, 100)
```

This is what I started with, predictably, but I have nowhere to go.

I tried using the array module, but I could not figure out how to work it, I am not the best at programming.
I tried using the following:

```
from random import *
number = randint(1,100)
print(number)
numberstore = number
while numberstore == number:
    number = randint(1,100)
print(number)
numberstore = number
```

I don't know how to make this work though.

Comment: do you mean "not choosen again" from another execution of the code ? Or inside the code you pick multiple values that should be unique ?

Comment: @azro I mean not chosen again in this program.

Comment: and how many distinct numbers do you want ?

Comment: @azro i would like something that works whatever the range is. Right now, I am running with a range of 1-100 as stated in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you're wanting something like this.

```
from random import *
numberstore = []

while True:
    number = randint(1,100)
    if number not in numberstore:
        numberstore.append(number)
        print(number)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of previous numbers

```py
from random import randint

PREVIOUS = set()

def get_unique_number():
    nb = randint(1,100)
    while nb in PREVIOUS: # if already generated, pick again
        nb = randint(1,100)
    PREVIOUS.add(nb) # save generated
    return nb

count = int(input("How many numbers do you want ?"))

for _ in range(count):
    print("unique number", get_unique_number())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the exact syntax, as I don't have an IDE now, but you could store all the possibilities inside a set and choose from those at random:

```
choices = set(range(1, 100))

while choices:
    number = random.choice(tuple(choices))
    print(number)
    choices.remove(number)
```

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track with the `while` loop, but there are some issues in your code.

Here's update version of your code:

```
from random import randint

number = randint(1, 100)
print("Random Number:", number)

numberstore = number

while numberstore == number:
    number = randint(1, 100)

print("New Random Number:", number)
```